# ERROR at the time of capybara installation

Tags: ruby, windows, capybara

I am trying to setup environment for Web Testing using Capybara & Cucumber. I am hitting command "`gem install capybara`" to install but getting an error on the terminal is:

```
ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'capybara' (>= 0), here is why: Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect return ned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed ( https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Anyone from us faced this issue on Windows 64 bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this issue is because -

- There is an **'SSL' certificate error**.
- When you try to connect to the 'rubygems.org' server via the command prompt, What you need to do is follow the instructions listed here: https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88#manual-solution-to-ssl-issue

> Basically you create a new '.pem' file and save it inside
>   'C:\Ruby21-x64\lib\ruby\2.1.0\rubygems\ssl_certs' folder.

NOTE: your path might be a little different but this is the basic idea!

Comment: You can mark your own answers as the accepted answer. Good for the statistics :)